# Create a detail view of a card view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

i have followed [this tutorial](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/02/android-recyclerview-cardview/) of a RecyclerView with Cardviews and now i would like to open a new activity to show the detailed information of the cardview the user clicks on.

Comment: **1)** The tutorial is not accessible without creating an account. **2)** The question is not clear **3)** You did not add any code. Also, there is a [Spanish StackOverflow](http://es.stackoverflow.com/) if you preffer it.

Comment: 1) u can see the tutorial without creating an account. 2)i'm sorry for that 3) thanx for the infor of the spanish StackOverflow i didnt know about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To this action you need to implement an `Interface` and implement it in your MainActivity , like a listener.

**OR**

You can use a onClickListener for any particular view. But if you want to start activity for the itemView adapter layout use the `holder.itemView` clicklistener in the `onBindViewHolder` method.

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context,YOUR_ACTICITY.class));
    }
});
```